# Can supernatural beings be possessed and claimed by spirits?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, werewolf-the-forsaken

I'm not sure about the spirit rules. Can supernatural beings be claimed or possessed?
(Didn't find any excepiton that says they cannot)

Answer (score 5):

### Yes

Any of the Ephemeral Beings (Ghost, Spirit or Angel) can do it if it possesses the correct Manifestation.

There are three possible manifestations that can be used:

1. **Fetter** : requires that the target has the Open condition. If successful the target gains the Urged condition (=Spirit-Urged of 1st Edition).
2. **Possess** : same as Fetter, but the target gains the Possessed condition instead of Urged (power used by the Spirit-Thieves of 1st Edition).
3. **Claimed** : requires that the target has the Controlled condition. If successful the target gains the Claimed condition (=Spirit-Claimed of 1st Edition).

Resistance is always handled through Resolve + Composure + Supernatural Tolerance (where Supernatural Tolerance = Blood Potency / Primal Urge / Gnosis  or the power trait used by the template).

Source: p224 - p 228 of the God-Machine rules update.

**For 1st Edition New World of Darkness**: the same information can be found in the Book of Spirits (see Claim on p139; Living Fetter on p143; Possession on p145). The Werewolf core book doesn't mention the Supernatural Tolerance for the resisting party.

Comment: so regardless which major splat you are immune to possession but not to urging?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, but generally it's not a good idea because supernatural beings may easily understand what is happening, and react appropriately.

In game terms, a supernatuarl being adds his "power trait" (Blood Potency, Gnosis, Primal Urge...) to Resistance rolls against the spirit